# Sqlserver query optimization in clause on big table

Tags: sql-server-2005, query-optimization

I have following query which scans big table unfortunately i do not have index on this column but often i have to run query on this column. is there a way i can optimize this query.

select * from match with (nolock) where CURRENT_STATE in ('ACT','REJ')

[image]

Total records in this table are 30280527

If i use top clause instead of selecting all records will it improve performance ?

Comment: Why don’t you _set_ an index then, and see whether it helps or not?

Comment: i also have lot of inserts in this table, index may cause performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you use a TOP clause it will improve performance proportional to the number of rows the clause excludes. However, you will only get back rows that are within the range specified by the TOP clause as well.

No, there is nothing you can do to optimize this query. It is so simple there is nothing there to work with. Your only option is to add an index, and declining to do so on the assertion that you have a lot of inserts and performance will suffer is foolishness. Yes, indexes do incur overhead, but that overhead is minuscule in comparison to their performance gains.

In fact, if you run a query like the one above at the same time that inserts are occurring, I suspect that it's quite possible that the amount of I/O and CPU needed to scan the table would incur more performance penalty than the overhead of maintaining an index and seeking it.

If you absolutely must keep the table index-free (because you have tested performance with an index added and the results are not acceptable), consider setting up some form of replication where you have an index-free table to accept inserts, and another table that occasionally receives data from the first table, and put the indexes on the second table and run your queries on that.